# Test debounce with marble diagram

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable, rxjs6

I have epic that debounce until it successfully call ping api. I tested successfully ping case. I'd like to use `import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';` and test when I cannot ping to 1st call, but success in 2nd with marble diagram. is there any example?

```
export const resendData = (action$, store$, {service}) => {
return action$
    .pipe(
    ofType(
        SOMETHING_FALL
    ),
    debounce(() => service.get('/api/ping').pipe(
        retryWhen(err =>
        err.pipe(
            scan((acc, _) => acc * 2, 2),
            delayWhen(val => timer(val * 1000))
        )
        ),
        catchError(_ => empty())),
    ),
    map(_ => retryAction()),
    );
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to do. Can you make a marble diagram what you want to test?

Comment: I mock service.get return as blow
`var callback = sinon.stub(service, 'get');`
`callback.onCall(0).returns(of(1).pipe(delay(2000), mergeMap( _ => throwError({}))));`
`callback.onCall(1).returns(of({}));`

Source is ('a|'). I would like to see epic will return retryAction when ping success on 2nd try. 
PS. I added edit question to have map operation.